# What should be the basic points to know while creating a logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo

Either using Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator, what are the basic rules that anyone should follow.
Currently I am working on a logo design and using Photoshop, but getting very confused about how to start to design a logo.
Any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Start by reading Paul Rand (not to be confused with Rand Paul, which is something else entirely), who many would consider the 'godfather' of modern logo design and corporate branding: http://www.paul-rand.com/foundation/thoughts_logosflags/#.VOQmEPnF-So

Answer (score 5):

I think there are enough basic rules to make this an answerable question. It's a bit broad of question, but the answer can be too.

- Read Paul Rand's thoughts on logos: http://www.paul-rand.com/foundation/thoughts_logosflags/#.VOQmEPnF-So Paul Rand is, to many graphic designers, the 'godfather' of modern logo design and corporate branding. You've probably seen dozens of his logos without knowing it.
- Sketch. Pencil. Paper. Sketch. Then Sketch some more. Then take a break. Then more sketching. Sketch, sketch, sketch. You can't do enough sketching. Sketching is where all the crazy ideas are free to flow out as fast as they can as you quickly jot them to paper.
- Like sketching, brainstorm. Brainstorm, brainstorm, brainstorm. Try to think of all the words that may have something to do with your subject no matter how tangential they may feel. Then do word association to find even more words and concepts.
- Watch this video by Aaron Draplin: https://vimeo.com/113751583 Aaron is a designer who I'd argue has kept some of the Paul Rand spirit alive in his own logo work. He's good at sketching loosely and then distilling an idea down to a nice, simple, iconic mark. I'd say his logo work is timeless as much as Rand's is. He's also really entertaining to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Always, always, always make the logo in black and white first. A good rule of thumb is that if the logo dosen't work in black and white, no amount of colors or gradients will fix it.